# Term for "bending in multiple directions at the same time" - "mind bending", actually

Tags: meaning, expressions, phrase-requests, terminology

I want to extend the expression "mind bending" to mean "mind bending in multiple directions at the same time".

My intuition to "mind bending" is an object becoming curved to roughly a quarter  circle - with no reference to the previous shape. So the "bending in multiple directions" could be a sequence of circle sections of random size and curvature. <sup>*</sup>

The term "mind curling" is the best I came up with - it would fit, except that it describes a well defined high level structure. The somewhat random aspect is relevant .

I like the term "mind bending" - so I prefer it as a base. But an alternative expression with the same meaning based on something else or novel would still interest me. My interpretation of "mind bending" is something like "rationally irritating in a structured way".

---

<sup>*</sup> While I find the expression fascinating in general, I can actually cite a source for the intended primary use. The lecture/work of art/emotional performance [Suic!de and Ment@l He@lth](https://youtu.be/eQNw2FBdpyE) of [Philosophy Tube](https://www.youtube.com/user/thephilosophytube) could be described as seriously irritating in a surprising number of ways, on rational and emotional level. Known terms like "mind bending" or "mind boggling" just do not cut it. So it deserves a new term. (And a content warning in relation to the topic of suicide.) (Ending with that word feels spooky, so it's continued.)

Comment: To send the mind of in all directions at once is to confuse.  Get out a thesaurus, look up ‘confuse’ and se if you find a word you feel fits your idea better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that *bending* does not necessitate there being only a single bend. Whether there is one bend or many, *bending* still applies. If you *twist and bend* something, it's not normally thought of as meaning just a single iteration of the action. If you bend something once, there's not to prevent you from bending it again—and in a different place.

Barring further clarification, **mind bending**, to me, remains the best choice.

---

However, if you want to dispense with *bending* itself, there are other possibilities.  (The following links all go to Merriam-Webster definitions.)

Many of the typical words don't include the idea of "structure", at least in terms of keeping the original intact: *[shattering](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shatter), [fragmenting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fragment), [splitting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/splitting), [randomizing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/randomize), [distorting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distort), [warping](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warping), [reconfiguring](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reconfigure), [mutating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutate)*.

Others do suggest a sense of *multiplicity* and also might be thought of in terms of "structure": *[bifurcating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bifurcate), [parallelizing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parallelizing), [multiplying](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multiply)*.

---

In line with the second set, I personally like **mind reiterating**. (Interestingly, I used the base word in the original paragraph I wrote without thinking about it.)

To [*reiterate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reiterate) means to do the same thing again, but not necessarily in exactly the same way or producing exactly the same effect:

> : to state or do over again or repeatedly sometimes with wearying effect

In terms of multiple bends, each bend could be a reiteration of the last one; each bend could have the same general structure as the last, but have its own unique direction and shape.

Comment: Yes, "mind warping" is describing it! Warping as when you take a rope made from strands by twisting them, make a loop, and twist it so much that it shortens -  and then let it go. A sequence of curves, locally well defined - but no overall structure. Each part is mind bending but can be understood - and as a whole, it's overwhelming - even while it is not random.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel  I should note that in your question you said you were looking for something structured—but in your comment you seem to say say that *warping* is not structured. So, I'm confused. But, regardless, I'm glad you got what you needed—albeit from one of the words I'd actually ruled out and listed as something I thought you didn't want. ;)